# read 1 or several lines in bash - make it work when pasting (in addition to typing manually)

Tags: bash, read, user-input

I read multiple answers with varying complexities. Most are working well when the input is typed manually.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20913871/1841533 .

Here is my sample code, very close to the one in that answer:

```
_delay_end_input_=2
printf "%s\n" "answer: "
IFS= read -d '' -n 1 theanswer
while IFS= read -d '' -n 1 -t ${_delay_end_input_} more ; do 
  theanswer="${theanswer}${more}"
done
```

This also works great when I type the answer manually, ie: character by character...

But if I paste a line (or several) : **it echoes the "remaining buffer" after each character is read**... making a mess of the display.

I haven't yet found a way to hide this, while keeping the normal echoing on screen. (ie, if typing or pasting, I still want to see what is typed/pasted)

Short example: Here is the (good) prompt while I type manually "abcd", character by character:

```
answer: abcd
```

But if I supply "abcd" by pasting it in a single moment with the mouse, it messes up the echoing by repeating after each character is read the remaining entire buffer:

```
answer: abcdbcdcdd
```

tl/dr: the snippet works great when entering character by character, but echoes remaining reading buffer after reading each char of a pasted entry.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a workaround... But I also hope someone gives out something better.

Corrected code: I hide the normal echo, and I echo it myself after each read:

```
stty_orig=`stty -g`  ### added this
stty -echo           ### added this
_delay_end_input_=2
printf "%s\n" "answer: "
IFS= read -d '' -n 1 theanswer
printf "$theanswer" >&2 ;  ### added this
while IFS= read -d '' -n 1 -t ${_delay_end_input_} more ; do
  printf "$more" >&2 ;  ### added this
  theanswer="${theanswer}${more}"
done

stty $stty_orig  ### added this
```

It seems up to now to do everything I needed... But I dislike printing to stderr that way... (maybe best to printf to /dev/tty instead?)

**edit**: a **big** drawback is : difficult to also handle "backspaces" or dels: if the person entering 1 or multiple lines of text wants to change something, it's quite hairy to interpret the corrective keys... Having a readline allowing 1 or several lines of input would be the best here... (maybe perl has one?)